# Xpages PDF creation using the XMLWorker class

Tags: itext, xpages

Using SSJS I've successfully created a PDF using the simple HTML parser that comes with iText but the simple HTML parser doesn't respect CSS and is very limited. I downloaded the XMLWorker class from the iText site and have tried to use that instead but my knowledge of working out how to call Java packages is too limited. All the examples I can find use Java and refer to the classes directly, eg.

`Document newPDF = new Document();`

But in SSJS we have to use dot notation, eg.

`var newPDF:com.itextpdf.text.Document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();`

This - I think - is where I stumble. My code looks like this:

```
function createLPO2(pReqDoc:NotesDocument) {

importPackage(com.itextpdf);
//importPackage(com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper);
importPackage(java.io);

var con = facesContext.getExternalContext();
var response:com.ibm.xsp.webapp.XspHttpServletResponse = con.getResponse();

response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"LPO_" + pReqDoc.getItemValueString("RequisitionNo") + ".pdf\"");

var newPDF:com.itextpdf.text.Document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document();
var writer = com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.getInstance(newPDF,response.getOutputStream());
var xmlWorkerHelper = com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();

var strHTML = getTestHTML(); //this is the HTML used in the examples on the iText site

xmlWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(writer, newPDF, new java.io.StringReader(strHTML));

newPDF.close();
writer.close();

facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

If I run this script as it is I get a script error on the Domino console. If I remove the comment on the line `importPackage(com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper);` it gives a completely different error. I suspect I have to import the XMLWorkerHelper package and not just the com.itextpdf package. I thought if I opened the jar file using a tool like 7-zip I could work out the path, which is how I arrived at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper

Is this right? If so, why does my script fail?

Comment: What Script error are you getting?

Comment: You have to import a package, not a class: *importPackage(com.itextpdf.tool.xml)*

Comment: Thanks Sven - I didn't know that. I'm completely new to Java although I've been working with Notes for many years. I have a good knowledge of client-side javascript and have found it easy to pick up server-side javascript, but Java is still a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob, 
seriously,  don't try to do that in SSJS. iText is all Java, if you try to mangle with it in a different language it will stress you out. Create a wrapper class that has a method that takes an OutputStream and whatever data (Document, View etc) you need. Obtain the OutputStream in your SSJS and call the function. Look for the XAgent XSnippet on OpenNTF and my blog series (the last two are missing - bear with me) on PDF creation. 
One word of caution: iText is GPL, so you either GPL your software too, buy a commercial iText license or look for alternatives like Apache PDFBox or Apache FOP. Ah the second caution: HTML to PDF is a Pita. You could look at a commercial tool like e.g. from Swing software (or change your approach)

Comment: Watch for an upcoming talk on Wrappers on NotesIn9

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accept you're right but I'm still lost. I looked at your blog and found the articles about XML and XSL:FO and XSLT. I understand the principles but the details of how I create a "wrapper class that takes an OutputStream" is still a complete mystery to me. I've spent far too long Googling for a beginner's guide to implementing Java in Xpages without success. For example I've found a lot of stuff about "managed beans" and how to point to them in "faces-config.xml" but nothing to say where to store a managed bean in an nsf. I guess a "wrapper class" is a managed bean?

Comment: Hi Rob,
To add a Java class to an XPage simply code one in the Code/Java design element (in pre 8.5.3 you would put it in webcontent/web-inf/src and add that to the build path). The wrapper is just a simple Java class that takes all needed parameters in. Follow [this example](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SLCVR) com.notessensei.tools.PDFFormatter is a wrapper class. Everything Java other than instantiating the class is inside, so your SSJS becomes lean and mean